# How can i separate the data from selected data

Tags: mysql, string, substring, navicat

I have a column in my table name as **URL** and it contains Multiple value like  "*https://www.google.com/#q=how+to+make+a+android+app*"
and

*http://www.bing.com/search?q=how+to+make+a+android+app&go=&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=how+to+make+a+android+app&sc=8-15&sp=-1&sk=*

I want to get data separately in output like

website =     https://www.google.com

Keyword =     how to make a android app.

Any Idea Plz, How can i get this in **MySql**.

Answer (score 0):

you can use substr() function in php to cut string. In your case, you can get the characters up to the end of 'https://www.google.com'.

read more at https://www.php.net/substr

in case you want to do it directly in your query, you can use substr() as well. Sql syntax goes like this:

> SELECT SUBSTR(column, start_position, desired_length) FROM table_name

*SELECT SUBSTR(column_name, 1, 20) FROM table_name;*

Comment: I want to do it in MYSQL, without using PHP... Sorry if my question did't make you understand that I want to do it in MYSQL ...

Comment: you can specify the length of characters to be returned using substr() e.g SELECT SUBSTR(column, start_position, desired_length) FROM table_name;

Comment: Thats Perfect what you suggested.But I am going to edit my question. As there are multiple links in URL field, So the length is not same in every link.

Comment: may I ask why you want to do this in sql directly? I don't think it will be possible to dynamically change the limit of characters without using variables first.

Comment: Because i am only allowed to access database and build some Excel report.

Comment: so what part of the url are you really going to get? do you intend to get only the base url up to '.com' only?